# Approximating a Banach space "vector- valued function" by "simple functions"

Tags: banach-spaces, approximation, hahn-banach-theorem

I'm trying to prove the following claim:

> Let $T$ be a compact (metric) space, and let $\mathcal{X}$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{K}$. Let $f : T \longrightarrow \mathcal{X}$ be a continuous function. Then in the Banach space $\mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{K}}(T)$ with the sup-norm, $\left \lVert f \right \rVert_{\mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{K}}(T)} = \sup_{t \in T}|f(t)|$, $f$ can be approximated in the norm-topology by "simple" functions of the form $g(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} h_{i}(t) x_{i}$, where $x_{i} \in \mathcal{X}$ and $h_{i}(t) \in \mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{K}}(T)$.

Here's my attempt:

The idea is to fix a finite dimensional subspace in $\mathcal{X}$ and approximate $f$ by vector-valued functions that live on that subspace.

By the Axiom of Choice, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ choose $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ recursively such that $x_{i+1}$ is not in $\text{span} (x_{1}, \cdots, x_{i})$. Let $\mathcal{M} = \text{span}(x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n})$. First recall that,

\begin{equation}
\phi: \mathcal{M} \longrightarrow \mathbb{K}^n, \quad \phi\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}x_{i}\bigg) = (\alpha_{1}, \cdots, \alpha_{n})^{T},
\end{equation}

is a linear isomorphism. For $1 \leq i \leq n$, define the projection maps,

\begin{equation}
\pi_{i} : \mathbb{K}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{K}, \quad \pi_{i} (\alpha_{1}, \cdots, \alpha_{n})^{T} = \alpha_{i},
\end{equation}

and consider the map $f_{i} = \pi_{i} \circ \phi$. For $v \in \mathcal{M}$, we can show that,

\begin{equation}
f_{i}(v) = f_{i}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}x_{i}\bigg) \leq C \lVert \alpha \rVert_{K^{n}} \leq CD \lVert v \rVert_{\mathcal{X}},
\end{equation}

for some $C, D > 0$. Since the latter expression is a semi-norm, by the Hahn-Banach Theorem there exists $F_{i} \in \mathcal{X}^{*}$ such that,

\begin{align}
 F_{i}(x) & \leq CD \lVert x \rVert \; \text{for all} \; x \; \text{in} \; \mathcal{X} \\
& F_{i} = f_{i} \; \text{on} \; \mathcal{M}
\end{align}

For $t \in T$, consider $f(t) \in \mathcal{X}$. For $1 \leq i \leq n$ , applying $F_{i}$, we have,
\begin{equation}
c_{i}(t) := F_{i}(f(t)), \quad c_{i}(t) \in \mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{K}}(T).
\end{equation}

Now let,

\begin{equation}
f_{n}(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i}(t) x_{i}.
\end{equation}

> I wish to claim that $\lVert f_{n} - f \rVert_{\mathcal{C}_{\mathbb{K}}(T)} $ goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

However, I can't see any reason as to why this must be the case. For example, if this were true, this would show that the $x_{i}'s$ that have been chosen from a Schauder basis for the range of $T$ in $\mathcal{X}$. Should the $x_{i}'s$ chosen above be chosen in a particular way so as to ensure that the aforementioned result holds true?

Clearly the above argument works if $\mathcal{X}$ is a finite dimensional vector space as we can "exhaust" $\mathcal{X}$ by building $\mathcal{X}$ recursively from 1-dimensional subspaces. I can't seem see to figure out how this argument would apply in the general case.

Please only provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that, since $T$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, it follows that the range $f(T)$ of $f$ is a compact subset in ${\cal X}$.

Thus, if we want an approximation with tolerance $\epsilon$, cover $f(T)$ with open balls of radius $\epsilon$...

Comment: Oh, yes. I suppose I can use this argument to cover $f(T)$ with finitely many open balls, and define $M$ using the centers of those finitely many balls. This point didn't cross my mind. I was trying to somehow use the continuity of $f$ to force the argument through.

Comment: Do you think the above argument which defines "projections" via the Hahn-Banach theorem still work? I'm getting a bit confused now on how to finish the argument.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the notation.  "$T: {\cal M} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^n$ implies that you are thinking of $T$ as a mapping.  Yet, you originally defined it as a compact metric space, and eventually resume treating it as as set ("$t \in T$").

So, either I am misreading, or there may be some typos.  We can take this into a discussion if you would like to pursue.

Comment: Sorry this was a typo. This is a mapping which shows $\mathcal{M}$ is isomorphic to $K^{n}$. I have relabeled it with $\phi$. It's not essential to the argument, I suppose, though. I just defined it so I can write out the form of the projectors defined on $\mathcal{M}$ explicitly.

Comment: I am unable to understand the indices and the index ranges in the construction of ${\cal M}$: are those correct?  In general, I recommend preferring prose to notation whenever possible.

Comment: I have edited the notation. The idea was to choose the $x_{i}'s$ recursively such that the next $x$ chosen isn't in the span of the previous $x's$ that have been chosen.

Comment: But I suppose this construction won't go through. Using your suggested approach, one would, I assume, cover $R(f)$ by finitely many balls, and use the centers of these balls to define $\mathcal{M}$, assuming this argument goes through.

Comment: Yes, you would use the centers of the balls, but you wouldn't even need to regard them as a generator system for any finite-dimensional vector space.  (I'll stop here, as you wanted only suggestions.  I am saying, however, that I believe you are overthinking.)

Your own construction, with a Schauder basis, though we haven't explored deeply for a proof or a counterexample, doesn't seem to make any use of the compactness of $C$, nor of the continuity of $f$.

Comment: True. My approach was to somehow approximate elements $R(f)$ in the norm-topology by elements that live in a finite dimensional vector space. Because clearly this result is true for $\mathbb{K}^n$. So my idea was to use my linear algebra intuition to prove this result under some kind of an approximation argument. But yes, both the domain and the range are compact, so they're as good as finite sets. However, I can't seem to complete the argument: my natural argument was to use the finite set to generate a vector space of finite dimension, and then run the argument based on the motivation...

Comment: I outlined above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92724/discussion-between-avs-and-user82261).

Comment: Hey. Check the chat.